# Cannot find symbol: KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry

Tags: java, keystore, x509

I'm trying to load the trusted certificates on a OS X/Java 7 system. According to Java's [Class KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html), there is a `KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry` type.

The following code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry);
```

Produces the following error:

```
HttpsCiphers.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry);
                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable TrustedCertificateEntry
  location: class KeyStore
```

I'm importing both `KeyStore` and `TrustedCertificateEntry`.

How does one utilize `TrustedCertificateEntry` or load the trusted certificate store?

---

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 12.5.0
      ...
```

Comment: In the Javadoc I cannot find `getInstance` factory that accepts `KetStore.Entry`..

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I know there's a `KeyStore.getDefaultType`, but I'm not interested in the default type (I don't even know what it is). But I'm very interested in trusted certificate types.

Comment: Well, I mean your code won't compile because there is no method that accepts the class - first, you pass it like `enum` value, not like `class` - second. Try fixing that first.

Comment: Oh, yes. You are correct. I'm getting a compile error from `javac`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry` was introduced in 1.5. You must be using an earlier Java, or maybe you have your own class called `KeyStore.`

In any case the code is nonsense. It should be `KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())`, or a `String` argument naming an explicit keystore type.

Comment: Thanks EJP. "... or a String argument naming an explicit keystore type." - what type is used for "trusted certificates"?

Comment: You're totally mixed up. A KeyStore is a file that can contain (1) key pairs, (2) trusted certificates, and (3) signed certificates. KeyStore *file* types are "JKS", "PKCS#12", etc. You're applying an entry-type descriptor to the file format parameter. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: "You're totally mixed up" - no argument. So, how do I load them all? Once I load all of them, then I'll move onto the next problem of enumerating trusted certificates.

Comment: You create the keystore as I showed in the second paragraph, then you use `KeyStore.load(),` `KeyStore.setCertificateEntry()`, etc., whatever you want to use. But why are you doing this in code? why not just use the `keytool?`

Comment: "But why are you doing this in code?" - I have an `SSLHandshakeException` (its a related problem, but one I can work through once I have the requisite information). I want to enumerate the trusted certificates and ensure the required root is present. A secondary problem is: I want to use the same code to enumerate the roots to Android to see what comes preloaded.

Comment: If you're getting a handshake exception, it isn't present. You don't need to write code to tell you that.

Comment: "If you're getting a handshake exception, it isn't present" - I don't believe that's not necessarily true. The required root could be present and other things could be causing the failure. For example, the certificate could be present but expired; or an intermediate certificate could be missing; or an interception proxy could be serving a different server cert for traffic inspection. The only way I can know for sure is to see the store an examine the certificates.

Comment: "It doesn't make sense..." - by the way, due to the way Stack Overflow is set up, I *cannot* simply ask how to do it (or ask for a reference for a book on how to do it). I need to attempt it and show some code. Hence the reason why some of this makes no sense at all. I'm simply bumbling around in the dark because I don't have the experience or the references needed.

Comment: If you're getting a handshake exception it will tell you what's wrong. The messages can be pretty opaque but they're not empty. I suggest you start again with the problem you're actually tying to solve, which is the handshake exception, instead of disappearing up this dirt track.

Answer (score 1):

According to [getInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29) method Javadoc (the one that accepts String), you should use it with one of the possible values:

- `jceks` - The proprietary keystore implementation provided by the SunJCE provider;
- `jks` - The proprietary keystore implementation provided by the SUN provider;
- `pkcs12` - The transfer syntax for personal identity information as defined in PKCS #12;

Information taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore).

For me it sounds like you're misusing `KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry` class as it seems to be intended to be used with `getEntry()/setEntry()` methods.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I guess this is where my Java disconnect is highlighted. I'm not interested in the different jceks's or jks's. I want all the certificates in the trusted certificate store (where ever that may be). The best I can tell (as someone who does not use Java regularly), that's a `KeyStore.TrustedCertificate` entry.

Comment: @jww unfortunately I'm not really good at certificate-related issues, but I hope my post was at least helpful to resolve compilation errors.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help. If I can ever assist in similar issues in OpenSSL, please let me know (I know OpenSSL fairly well).